# ReactJS Conditional Rendering - else if doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm in the stage of learning JS and React and I'm not sure why else if doesn't work in the code below. Anyone can help me?

```
  function Item({ name, isPacked }) {
  if (isPacked) {
    return (
      <li className="item">
        {name} {isPacked && " ✔"}
      </li>
    );
  } else if (!isPacked) {
    return (
      <li className="item">
        {name} {isPacked && " ❌"}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default function PackingList() {
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>Sally Ride's Packing List</h1>
      <ul>
        <Item isPacked={true} name="Space suit" />
        <Item isPacked={true} name="Helmet with a golden leaf" />
        <Item isPacked={false} name="Photo of Tam" />
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? Also, using `{isPacked && " ❌"}` when you just checked `!isPacked` means it will never be displayed.

Comment: Please provide some more info. What exactly isn't working? Are there any errors? etc..

Comment: You don't need an if/else there. You can use a [ternary statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) in one line: `{name} {isPacked ? '✔' : '❌'}`

Comment: @Spectric yes I can use logical AND and maybe ternary operator but I wanted to test with IF-Else if. Im not getting any error message I'm just expecting in the third component <Item> to get X next to the text.

Comment: @Andy can you please explain me why I can't use If/else if there?

Comment: You won't get an error because the code works - it just doesn't work the way you want it to. Remove the `isPacked` checks from within the if/else as Spectric pointed out - you've already made them. PS - I said you don't _need_ it, not that you can't _use_ it.

Comment: @Andys so in practise it's better to use Logical AND and ternary operators rather than if/else if?

Comment: [If you're using `if` you don't need the else.](https://pastebin.com/xJdFdmtz).

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
function Item({ name, isPacked }) {
    return (
        <li className="item">
            {name} {isPacked ? '✔' : '❌'}
        </li>
    );
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the template string here.

Comment: What is the alternative could you share please

Comment: See my previous comment, or the other answer.

Comment: I just checked it, thank you for information.

Answer (score 0):

you actually tested if the isPacked true or false so try this code:

```
function Item({ name, isPacked }) {
    return (
      <li className="item">
        {name}  {isPacked ? "✔" : "❌" }
      </li>
    );
}
```

{isPacked ? "✔" : "❌" } so this line of code is equal to:

```
  if(isPacked == true){
      return "✔";
    }else{
      return "❌";
    }
```

You can get some helpful examples Here https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html.